# Android - Open File with another specific app

Tags: android

My app downloads .zip, .js, and .png and I want to open them with another app called Blocklauncher. Blocklauncher has a specific activity setup to open these files. There is an intent filter setup for .js files, so those open as they should. But .zip and .png files aren't so easy. Heres what the .png file activity looks like in Blocklaunchers manifest

```
<activity android:name="net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.api.ImportSkinActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.action.SET_SKIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity-alias android:name="net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.ImportSkinActivity"     
android:exported="true" 
android:targetActivity="net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.api.ImportSkinActivity" />
        <activity android:name="net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.api.ImportTexturepackActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.action.SET_TEXTUREPACK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Anyone have any idea's? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well if BlockLauncher Imports Scripts with this:

```
Intent intentMTex = new Intent("net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.action.IMPORT_SCRIPT");
Uri texMPath = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/","Mech_Texture.zip"));
intentMTex.setDataAndType(texMPath, "text/plain");
```

Have you tried changing

```
intentMTex.setDataAndType(texMPath, "text/plain");
```

and

```
Intent("net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.action.IMPORT_SCRIPT);
```

to

```
intentMTex.setDataAndType(texMPath, "image/png");
```

and

```
Intent("net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.action.SET_SKIN);
```

?

Please tell me you did startActivity() :P